# Keep indentation of a Snowflake object's SQL definition with row output

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When you define a SQL definition for a snowflake object (i.e. VIEW, TASK ... etc/) you can get it using metadata definition (ex : SHOW VIEWS -> text) or using GET_DDL function.

In the Snowflake WEBui you can then select the output which display the original indentation of SQL code which makes it more readable.
I want to bulk recreate objects in Snowflake and I would like to keep this indentation in object's SQL definition.
Unfortunately when I bulk-generate my queries in Snowflake, the SQL definition stands as a row with SQL definition flattened/not indented.

Example :

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT 
    'Hello' AS col_1, 
    'World' AS col_2,
    '!' AS col_3
;

SHOW VIEWS LIKE 'my_view';

SELECT "text" FROM table(result_scan(last_query_id()));
```

-> Copy paste result get me the following query instead of indented one

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS  SELECT       'Hello' AS col_1,       'World' AS col_2,      '!' AS col_3;
```

Comment: In Snowflake's original UI, any time you see blue text for a row in the grid it means that it's multi-line or has compacted whitespace. You can click on the text and it will pop up a window with the original text. In this case it will include the original formatting.

Comment: @GregPavlik, yes but i would like to be able to generate several queries and being able to copy paste the result easily for a bulk usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately when I bulk-generate my queries in Snowflake, the SQL definition stands as a row with SQL definition flattened/not indented

The carriage return characters are still present in resultset, but the UI rows have constant height.

[image]

There is also download button to get it as "CSV".

[image]

---

WebUI is not the only way of interacting with Snowflake. Here the same query using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/):

[image]

Comment: Nice idea with the 'export' button. Using Snowflake WebUI (not Snowsight) i can select 'CSV' then 'Show in dialog' and can have several queries nicely indented.
Too bad each value is surrounded with double quotes. That doesn't allow me to copy/past the content into worksheet. But this was close.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a long time after the best solution for me to keep indentation in bulk query generation in Snowflake UI was to replace **\n** by **\r\n**.

Like this it keeps me the original indentation when i copy / paste my query in UI.